# MFRC522 Communication Failure

Tags: esp32, rfid

I'm using TTGO ESP32 and I've got an MFRC522 from AliExpress.

I've soldered connector pins to the board itself (both for ESP32 and MFRC522) and I'm using jumper wires female-to-female to connect themselves.

However, using an example sketch (DumpInfo) from miguelbalboa's RFID library, it says communication failure and scanning 3 different key cards or the key fob doesn't output anything.

```
Firmware Version: 0xFF = (unknown)
WARNING: Communication failure, is the MFRC522 properly connected?
```

This is my current pinout scheme:

```
(MFRC - ESP32)
SDA (SS) -> 33
SCK -> 25
MISO -> 27
MOSI -> 26
RST -> 32
```

And, of course also GND to G and 3.3V to 3.3V.

I've also tried SDA and SCK to connect to 21 and 22, respectively but no luck.
Though I have a DS1307 RTC module and microSD card adapter module and connected accordingly and it's working fine, by using Dupont wires, with the same method.

A manufacturer's defect or still I'm making an error somewhere?

You can see TTGO's ESP32 pinout diagram and also a picture of MFRC522 [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK5m0.jpg)  wired using jumper wires. I may be using (again) the wrong pins. The red LED on the MFRC522 is stable, though.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE!**
The issue has been fixed, just after finding this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64998779/5847989) by bat macumba. I'll leave the question here, in case someone stumbles into the same problem.